# Ingress with two react apps not loading css

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, react-router, nginx-ingress

I have a k8s cluster with two react apps. One app with the root path loads fine, but the second app fails to load with the following errors:

[image: console log]
[image: network log]

I have tried several approaches given by those who faced a similar issue to no success. This has come about because I have two react apps and I need them both. Without routing them through ingress, they run fine.

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: co7-ingress
   annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
 spec:
   rules:
   - http:
       paths:
  
       - path: /api/auth/
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           serviceName: usermanagement-service 
           servicePort: 5001

       - path: /admin_login
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           serviceName: adminweb
           servicePort: 4000

       - path: /
         backend:
           serviceName: web
           servicePort: 5000
```

My ingress is pretty big with about 9 different backends.. but the relevant part is shown above. Any suggestions? because this issue is bugging me!

Comment: Please edit your question by providing the full Ingress config that you use and do not paste screenshots of errors, use plain text instead as it is hard to work with that.

Comment: I have edited my ingress. What I am struggling with primarily is correctly routing two separate react apps using ingress